# Nowhere Baire spaces

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Studying the article "[Barely Baire spaces](https://eudml.org/doc/210989)" of W. Fleissner and K. Kunen, using stationary sets, they show an example of a Baire space whose square is nowhere Baire (we call a space $X$ nowhere Baire if there is a family $\mathcal{D}=\{D_{i}:  i\in\omega \}$  of open dense sets so that $\bigcap \mathcal{D}$ is empty).

They comment that generalizing the example mentioned above it is possible to construct a space $X$ so that $X^m$ is nowhere Baire and $X^n$ is Baire for all $n<m$. More specifically, if $m\leq\omega$, they construct a space $X$ such that $X^m$ is nowhere Baire and $X^n$ is Baire for all $n <m$. For the proof they consider $\{A_{y}:y\in m^{\omega}   \}$ be disjoint stationary subsets of $C_{\omega}\mathfrak{c^{+}}=\{\beta<\mathfrak{c^{+}} : cf(\beta)=\omega\}$ and $B_{y}=\bigcup\{A_{y^{\prime}}: y^\prime \in m^{\omega} \hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{and}\hspace{0.1cm} y^{\prime}(i)\not= y(i)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{for all }\hspace{0.1cm} i\in\omega\}$. Finally the space is $$X=\{\langle y, f   \rangle \in m^{\omega} \times J_{\mathfrak{c^{+}}}: f^{*}\in B_{y}\},$$ where
    $$\begin{array}{cccl} 
 *:& (\mathfrak{c^{+}})^{\omega} &\rightarrow & \mathfrak{c^{+}}\\
 & f & \rightarrow & f^{*}= \sup_{n\in \omega} \{f(n)\} \in\mathfrak{c^{+}} \\
 \end{array}$$
To demonstrate the first affirmation, motivated by the previous example, I considered the following countable family of dense open sets.
For any $i, j<m$, $k<\omega$ let us define $D_{ijk}\subseteq X^m$ by 
$$D_{i j k}=\{\langle \langle y_0, f_0 \rangle,\cdots,\langle y_{m-1}, f_{m-1} \rangle\rangle \in X^m :  y_{i}\not=y_{j} \hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{and}\hspace{0.1cm}
min (f^*_i, f^*_j) > max (f_{i}(k), f_{j}(k) )   \}.$$ 
I got to prove that, for any $i, j<m$, $k<\omega$, $D_{i j k}$ is an open and dense set in $X^m$. Finally I claim that $$\bigcap_{\substack{i,j<m \\ k<\omega}} D_{ijk} =\emptyset.$$ For this suppose otherwise, then there is $\langle \langle y_0, f_0 \rangle,\cdots,\langle y_{m-1}, f_{m-1} \rangle                                        \rangle \in \bigcap_{\substack{i,j<m \\ k<\omega}} D_{ijk}$. Note that $f^{*}_{0}=\cdots=f^{*}_{m-1}=\gamma\in C_{\omega}\mathfrak{c^{+}}$. But so far I could not come to a contradiction. My questions are the following: (1) I am on the right path to reach the contradiction, otherwise (2), I would like if there exists another family of dense open sets for the contradiction.

Thanks a lot.